# Forçar que dois elementos sempre ocupem o mesmo espaço

Tags: css

Como fazer com que dois elementos, sempre ocupem o mesmo espaço, independente do navegador e do tamanho da tela?

Usei o `transform translateX` porém, ao testar no celular não funcionou, aqui coloquei `-18px`, na minha aplicação tive que colocar `-45px` para desktop e `-43px` para celular:

```css
#plus {
    transform: translateX(-18px) rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">

<i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
<i id="plus" class="fas fa-minus"></i>
```

A ideia é que o segundo ícone irá girar para alternar entre `+` e `-`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ambos os elementos ocuparem o mesmo lugar, use `position: absolute` no ícone `#plus` e ele ficará sobreposto ao primeiro, mas é preciso colocá-los dentro do mesmo contêiner, pode ser um `span` porque não altera o layout. Mas o `span` precisa também de um `position: relative`:

```css
span.icone{
   position: relative;
   background: red; /* apenas para mostrar a área ocupada pelo span */
}

#plus {
   transform: rotate(90deg);
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">

<span class="icone">
   <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
   <i id="plus" class="fas fa-minus"></i>
</span>
```

Neste caso você não precisa reposicionar um dos elementos com `translate`.

No caso do Safari, é preciso adicionar o prefixo `-webkit-` no `transform`:

```
#plus {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

**Alternativa com classes nativas**

Pode usar classes nativas do componente para *empilhar* os dois ícones, fazendo apenas a rotação do segundo via CSS. Seguindo o mesmo exemplo anterior, colocando os ícones dentro de um `span`, coloque a classe `fa-stack` no contêiner e a classe `fa-stack-1x` em cada ícone (o `1x` é o tamanho normal do ícone):

```css
.rot {
   transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">

<span class="fa-stack">
   <i class="fas fa-minus fa-stack-1x"></i>
   <i class="fas fa-minus fa-stack-1x rot"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: valeu @Bacco e sam, não conhecia essas classes do font awesome

Comment: .............